# How do I change the width of Jupyter notebook's cell's left part?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I already increase the width of the jupyter notebook's cell on my browser with this

```
.container {
    width:100% !important;
}
```

However, I would also like to narrow the left part of the text cell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVU50.png)

For the above picture I would like shrink the part `div.prompt.input_prompt`.

Is it possible to do it with just css? how?

Also, if this can be done, how to empty left part automatically for all non-code cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt width is set in [notebook/static/notebook/less/cell.less#L80](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/0e453e750c042e2f64d5a19a228c871d7a19fd03/notebook/static/notebook/less/cell.less#L80), so you could do something like:

```
/* Narrow the prompts */
.prompt {
    min-width: 10ex;
}

/* Hide prompts altogether for non-conda cells */
.cell:not(.code_cell) .prompt {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: .cell:not(.codecell) .prompt {
    display: none;
} would hide all cells in fact.

Comment: Should be .cell:not(.codecell).prompt {
    display: none;
} no space between .codecell) and .prompt to pick class cell with (not codecell type) and class prompt

Comment: I don't think so, since the .prompt is a child element of the .cell element. So what we're attempting to select is all .prompt elements which are contained within (a .cell element which doesn't have class codecell). That sounds like what you wanted. Have I got something confused?

Comment: I got what you mean, but in practice it seems leaving a space between them would simply make all .prompt invisible. Yet if I use .cell:not(.codecell) > .prompt {
    display: none;
}   this would have the same effect as the one leaving no space in them. Quiet strange here...

Comment: Right, so my version doesn't work because the class is actually `code_cell`, not `codecell`. The direct-descendent version works because in code cells, the _input_ prompt is wrapped in another div, whereas in text cells, it's a direct child of the cell. It doesn't work for the output prompts. I'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```html
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.prompt_container{display:none !important}</style>"))
```

`enter code here`it will make left part of the all cell hide and give more space to work Example Here:-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2kAd.jpg)

Comment: This works for cell input part, do you know what to do to expand cell output also?